# HMAC-SHA256 in Java/ Translate from C#

Tags: java, c#, .net, eclipse, encryption

I have this piece of code in C#:

```
byte[] bytes = Encoding.Default.GetBytes("secret key");
int value = checked((int)Math.Round((currentDateTime - dateTimeOf1970).TotalSeconds));
HMACSHA256 hMACSHA = new HMACSHA256(bytes);
string text2 = this.toHexString(hMACSHA.ComputeHash(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(value.ToString() + "/" + url)));
```

where the method toHexString is this:

```
private string toHexString (byte[] bytes)
    {
        string text = "";
        checked
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
            {
                byte b = bytes[i];
                int num = (int)b;
                string text2 = num.ToString("X").ToLower();
                if (text2.Length < 2)
                {
                    text2 = "0" + text2;
                }
                text += text2;
            }
            return text;
        }
    }
```

Now I'd like to have that in Java, and as my Java skills are not as well as my C# skills I'm figuring out how to translate it. The toHexString method I translated like this:

```
private static String toHexString (byte[] bytes) {
    String text = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
        byte b = bytes[i];
        int num = (int) b;
        String text2 = Integer.toHexString(num);
        if (text2.length() < 2) {
            text2 = "0" + text2;
        }
        text += text2;

    }

    return text;

}
```

This works very well, produces the same output as the C# version.

Now to the other method (with the HMCAS-SHA256), thats my go on translating it:

```
//creating the timestamp
    long timestamp = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000;
    //getting the int value of it
    int value = (int) timestamp;

    //just a string that is the value of the hmac
    String input = String.valueOf(value) + "/" + url;
    //new hmac instance
    Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    //my secret key where bytes is "my key".getBytes();
    SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(bytes, "HmacSHA256");
    sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
    //trying to have as string
    String txt2 = toHexString (sha256_HMAC.doFinal(input.getBytes()));
```

Problem is that it doesnt produce the same output,

C# version (how it should be):

```
12eb558b98dd9a5429e7676640f3dd4122941a575ffa9dc20318...
```

Java version:

```
fffffff8fffffff87215ffffffb232ffffffeeffffff9069fffffffc6d4cffffffb667ff...
```

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Your C# version can be improved by getting rid of the whole "if length is less than 2, prepend a 0" bit and changing the `ToString()` parameter from `X` to `X2`. Another improvement would be using a `StringBuilder` to build `text` instead of doing a bunch of concatenations.

Comment: Thank you, just programmed it very quickly, but will surely improve it with the things you suggested once I figured how it works in Java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your main problem is that your Java `toHexString()` method is screwed up.

Java is always working with signed values, therefore `Integer.toHexString(num);` returns a lot of negative 32-bit numbers (you can see the `ff` in the output.

Therefore if you convert a byte to an (unsigned) int you always have to add `& 0xFF`:

```
Integer.toHexString(0xff & num);
```

Anyway a byte-array-to-hex-string method is available in a lot of libraries. Therefore it is not necessary to code it again. I prefer the `Hex` class from apache commons codec library.

BTW: You are using the default encoding in C# and Java but even on the same machine this does not necessarily means the encoding is the same. Use a fixed one like UTF-8 instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that fixed the problem. I also edited the encoding so that I only use UTF-8 now.